# Under which theories can a subclass be a member of its superclass, and a member of itself?

Tags: type-theory

I am relearning semantic web technologies and foundational mathematics. Currently, I am trying to understand the nature of whatever theory underpins [RDFS](https://www.w3.org/TR/PR-rdf-schema): is it a set theory (and if so, what kind?), a type theory (likewise?), a [description logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_logic) (ditto?), or something else?

The relations that hold in RDFS include the following:

- **(1)** `rdfs:Class` is a subclass of `rdfs:Resource`;
- **(2)** `rdfs:Resource` is a member of `rdfs:Class`; and
- **(3)** `rdfs:Class` is a member of `rdfs:Class`.

Additionally:

- **(4)** the `rdf:type` relation "indicates that a resource is a member of a class"; and
- **(5)** the `rdfs:subClassOf` relation "specifies a subset/superset relation between classes".

See the upper-left nodes in this diagram from the [RDFS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/PR-rdf-schema):

[image: Graph diagram showing subclass and membership relations between RDFS core classes and core properties.]

If I understand correctly, then whatever theory underpins RDFS, it has the following properties:

- if it is a set theory, then it is [non-well-founded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory), due to **(3)**.
- if it is a set theory, then, due to **(5)** it could be said to follow *Set Theory and its Logic* (Quine, 1969) in taking it to be the case that (pp.1-4, emphasis mine):

  > **Sets are classes. ... Basically 'set' is a synonym of 'class'** [because] the distinction [between sets (classes capable of being members) and 'proper classes' (classes *not* capable of being members)] emerges only in systems that admit [proper] classes, and even in such systems the classes we have to do with tend to be sets rather than [proper] classes until we get pretty far out.

My main question is: am I correct? If not, please explain the way in which I am mistaken.

My secondary question follows. RDFS has one [standout elegance](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_introduction): its "property-centric approach ... allows anyone to extend the description of existing resources, one of the architectural principles of the [Semantic] Web." Beyond that, it seems to be a mongrel application of various theories. Perhaps there is an underlying consistency and elegance I am failing to notice, that falls under some cohesive heading. Is there a name for the branch of mathematical theory underpinning RDFS?

Comment: Admittedly, my respect to Quine as a logician has just diminished after reading his quote.

Comment: Also, you seem to be actually interested in *type* theory and not at all in *set theory*.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using a rather out-dated version of the RDF Schema specification? Also, note that in, at least, the current specification, it is meant as a less formal presentation of the formal semantics given in the [RDF Semantics specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/). The [RDF Semantics specification takes priority over the the RDF Schema specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_introduction).

Comment: @DerekElkins, thanks for your points :) I used https://www.w3.org/TR/PR-rdf-schema/ as the basis for my question primarily because it includes the diagram that I used above, a visualisation that I hoped would improve the clarity of my question. I used it secondarily because, unlike later RDFS specs, it is presented as a single cohesive document. This helped me to keep my question concise. I understand and agree that the RDF Semantics specification takes priority over the the RDF Schema specification, but AFAICT, nothing in RDF Semantics contradicts **(1)...(5)** above.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the first part of your question:

> if it is a set theory, then it is non-well-founded, due to (3).

The class of all classes is a class in set theories like ZFC. That is because the axioms of ZFC do not allow just any set to be defined. Classes are all those sets which cannot be defined in ZFC.

In response to the second part:

> if it is a set theory, then, due to (5) it could be said to follow Set Theory and its Logic (Quine, 1969) in taking it to be the case that (pp.1-4, emphasis mine):

> > Sets are classes. ... Basically 'set' is a synonym of 'class' [because] the distinction [between sets (classes capable of being members) and 'proper classes' (classes not capable of being members)] emerges only in systems that admit [proper] classes, and even in such systems the classes we have to do with tend to be sets rather than [proper] classes until we get pretty far out.

This seems to just be arguing that if the term class is not used in a particular set theory, then it may have the same meaning as the term set.